# What is the difference between the two Django post_save signals

Tags: python, django, django-signals

I'm confused between why some tutorials and guides write two different post_save signal like below

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

when the profile can be saved by calling the save() method in one approach itself

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        profile = Profile(user=instance)
        profile.save()
```

Comment: Both create() and save() are the same in Django, you just use create if you want the object to be create in one liner

Comment: The question is about why some tutorials use two functions with different parameters for django signals to  perform some operation and one such example is given above.

Comment: i don't know why they split into 2 tbh, `post_save` can has `created` parameter in it to check if the save() is used to create new object or update existing object. You can write `instance.profile.save()` in the `else` statement of `if created:` and it still behave the same. So create an extra function for the post_save signal is unnecessary

Comment: That at least was helpful. Thank you for your response.

Comment: This is not a django thing. This is actually a python thing. So, there aren't two different post_save methods. you can either get the "created" param by specifying it in the function definition or it will be available in "kwargs" anyways. that is how keyword arguments work in python. read up on them to see different usecases.